# Excel Line Chart Chop x-axis Upon Empty Values

Tags: excel, charts

I have an excel line chart which its x axis holds time values and the y axis holds an average stock price.

lets say for example that the x axis starts from 9 - 18 with jumps of 5 minutes between each value. Now, my question is how to ignore x axis values when there is no value for the price. What I mean is that the source data of the chart is set to the whole x axis but since there is only price data till 14, i would like the chart to present only x axis and y axis till 14.

Many thanks,
Omer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following data setup:

[image]

Take the following steps.

1. Define two named ranges `x_Axis` &  `y_Axis` as shown below. See Refers To: box for x_Axis formula. y_Axis formula is the same, except replace `chart!$A$1` with `chart!$B$1`

[image]

1. Name your x-Axis series value as chart!x_Axis

[image]

1. Name your y-Axis series value as chart!y_Axis

[image]

I just realized that I may have transposed x & y Axis in my example! But, I think you get the point :) Also, important note. This set-up assumes that there is no other data present in columns A and B.